# Failing to match all buttons excluding first

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div class="breadcrumbs row">
  <button><a href="#">One</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">Two</a></button>
  <h1><button><a href="#">Three</a></button></h1>
</div>
```

Troublesome CSS

```
.breadcrumbs button:not(:first-of-type)::before {
  content: ' / ';
  cursor: default
}
```

I want to match all buttons, excluding the first, in `.breadcrumbs` and prepend them with `/`. Why doesn't my rule work?

Edit *(forget the most important question)*: What CSS rule would achieve what I want?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7drpqfqb/)

Comment: It works for me. Or do you mean you want to insert `/` before the button inside `h1` too?

Comment: @Oriol Did you watch the fiddle? I want it to output `One / Two / Three`. Now it's not getting the button inside the h1.

Comment: You misunderstood `:first-of-type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers using `:not(:first-of-type)` looks for first of type in its parent element and for this

```
<h1><button><a href="#">Three</a></button></h1>
```

`button` is first element of that type inside its parent which is `h1`

Change the selector for your button elements as follows

**CSS**

```
.breadcrumbs > button:not(:first-child)::before, 
.breadcrumbs > h1:not(:first-child) > button::before{
  content: ' / ';
  cursor: default
}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7drpqfqb/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the last button is within a `<h1>`, and it is its first child there.

You can add a second CSS selector that matches all `<h1>` child elements, except when in first place, like so:

```
.breadcrumbs button:not(:nth-child(1))::before,
.breadcrumbs h1:not(:nth-child(1)) button::before {
  content: ' / ';
  cursor: default
}
```

---

This also works, but, as pointed ou in the comments, is invalid HTML:

```
<button><h1><a href="#">Three</a></h1></button>
```

Comment: I was reading [this about aria](https://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/#second) and it seems to me that it encourages the use of button inside h1 to signal that it's a button. But I guess I could juste use a `a`...

Comment: The problem is that the [content model](https://w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model) of [`button`](https://w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) elements is [phrasing content](https://w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), and that doesn't include [`h1`](https://w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) elements. [`a`](https://w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is phrasing content but is also forbidden because it's [interactive content](https://w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0).

Comment: `button` inside `h1` is OK, but the opposite isn't.

Comment: @Oriol Yes I see it now

Answer (score 0):

Because your HTML is not structured enough. The rule of yours only works if every child element of breadcrumbs is a **button tag**.

So take out the **h1 tag** around the third button and you are in business.

Comment: I want it there for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7drpqfqb/1/), where I've removed the `not()`, the first and last buttons get prefixed by `/`.

This is because the 3rd button *is* the `:first-of-type` inside it's parent `<h1>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the button inside the h1 has a different parent element than the others. `:first-of-type` means the first inside a given parent element.